# how do I sort related products by position? magento 1.6

Tags: magento-1.6, sorting

Sort order of related products seems to be same with sort order of category products.

I would like to use position for sorting.
when I tried to set position fields of related products and reindex category products, nothing happen.

Does someone know how to edit specifically for related products?

Sorry Amit

I can't understand your solution. 
I just would like to use magento default function.

Usually, if I set positional order in related product tab in product editing page.
It can use.

I searched the internet and somebody says `related.php` file has a bug in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008076/sort-order-of-related-products-not-working-in-magento-1-6).
Do you think so?

`core>Mage>Catalog>Block>Product>List>Related.php`

Original

```
$this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
        ->addStoreFilter()
```

to

```
$this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
        ->setOrder('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
        ->addStoreFilter()
```

but this solution also not working for my site.

Comment: If I set the position value of related products under the respective product's tab in the backend, the related products are shown in the specified order. That does not work for you?

Comment: yes I tried but the sort order seems to follow "created at" setting which i use in default config setting for category.

Answer (score 1):

You can not  sort related product Collection  by using  position sort field of category

First you  need to add `catalog_category_product` table in related product Collection.

Because

`One product` may be included on `different different categories` that product have `different position on different  category`,therefore  for this reason on `you can only join a category`.

```
$collection->joinField('category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    '*',
    'product_id=product_id',
    null,
    'left'
);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id',5);
```

### Example:

Suppose  a product is included in two category cat1  and cat2.From admin>Manage Category>

you have set different sort for `Cat1-> 5, Cat2->8.`  That time you  will face the  issue.

Comment: Excellent.. +1 for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom module to do this. The *sorting* function is for Magento 1.9.x though (see code block below). It might as well be implemented into your template file, but I did not try this.

```
public function custom_FilterSort_relatedProducts($_product, $viewType) {
    if( $viewType == 'related' ) :
        $_collection = $_product->getRelatedLinkCollection();
    elseif( $viewType == 'upsell' ) :
        $_collection = $_product;
    endif;
    foreach ($_collection as $link):
        if( $viewType == 'related' ) :
            $_entityId = $link->getLinkedProductId();
            $relatedProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($link->getLinkedProductId());
        elseif( $viewType == 'upsell' ) :
            $_entityId = $link->getEntityId();
            $relatedProduct = $link;
        endif;
        $relatedData[$_entityId]['position'] = $link->getPosition();
        $relatedData[$_entityId]['status'] = $relatedProduct->getStatus();
        $relatedData[$_entityId]['avalaibility'] = $relatedProduct->getStockItem()->getIsInStock();
        if( $relatedData[$_entityId]['status'] == 2 || $relatedData[$_entityId]['avalaibility'] == 0 ) {
            unset($relatedData[$_entityId]);
        }
    endforeach;
    uasort($relatedData, function($first, $last) {
        return $first['position'] - $last['position'];
    });
    return $relatedData;
}
```